# Decide if direct children of element are certain tags

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to write this in `BeautifulSoup`?

```phyton
for node in soup:
  if node is in ["a", "b", "i", ...]: # node is tag of type `a` or `b` ...
    # we are probably on the text level
    textLevelFlag = true
  else:
    # "we are higher"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test if your tag has only text elements you can try this:

```
if hasattr(node, contents) and len(node.contents) == 1 and isinstance(node.contents[0], NavigableString):
    textLevelFlag = true
else:
    something else
```

Comment: But NavigableStrings can be everywhere and they are. I need to distinguish Tags, e.g. with isinstance method, but more precisely (e.g. isinstance(node, Tag of type "href"))

Comment: Hmm I guess I didn't understand the question. Are you looking only for nodes that have text content? Or do you need a more generic way of deciding if a one of nodes children is in the list?

Comment: I need to find out if the node is of type Tag and what tag (e.g. a, b, i) Im sorry I wrote href (my fault)

Comment: Use node.contents collection then. It contains all children nodes, including NavigableStrings and others. You can get tag name using tag.name.